# Error trying to traverse an array in Eiffel

Tags: multidimensional-array, syntax, syntax-error, traversal, eiffel

I get an error `unknown identifier 'start'`

my code:

```
visit_table(table: ETABLE)
    local
        t_array: ARRAY[ARRAY[ELEMENT]]
        b_header: BOOLEAN
        row_index: INTEGER
    do
        t_array := table.t_array
        b_header := table.b_header
        table.content := "<table>"
        row_index := 0

        from t_array.start
        until t_array.off
        loop

            table.content := table.content + "<tr>"
                from t_array.item.start
                until t_array.item.off
                loop
                    if row_index = 0 and b_header = TRUE then
                        table.content := table.content + "<th>" + t_array.item.content + "</th>"
                    else
                        table.content := table.content + "<td>" + t_array.item.content + "</td>"
                    end
                end
                table.content := table.content + "</tr>"
                row_index := row_index + 1
        end

        table.content := table.content + "</table>"
    end
```

I just want to parse through the objects of the 2d array and wrap html tags around them.
Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `ARRAY` does not inherit `TRAVERSABLE` that provides features `start`, `after`, `forth` and `item`. Therefore, arrays cannot be traversed using these features. Instead, the traversal is usually done using item indexes that start from `lower` and finish at `upper`. So, in your code there would be two variables `i` and `j` (one for the inner loop and another for the outer loop) of type `INTEGER` and the loops like

```
from
    j := t_array.lower
until
    j > t_array.upper
loop
    ... t_array [j] ... -- Use item at index `j`.
    j := j + 1 -- Advance to the next element of the array.
end
```

An alternative is to use an iteration form of the loop:

```
across
    t_array as x
loop
    ... x.item ... -- Use current item of the array.
end
```

The latter approach is closer to the one used in your current code, so you may prefer it more. Note that, in this case there is no need to call `start`, `off` and `forth`, because this is done automatically.

Finally, it's possible to use your current code, but iterate over `linear_reprentation`. For that you would need 2 more local variables `p` and `q` of types `LINEAR [ARRAY [ELEMENT]]` and `LINEAR [ELEMENT]` respectively. The first one would be initialized with `p := t_array.linear_representation` and the outer loop would use `p.start`, `p.after`, `p.item` and `p.forth`. The second one would be initialized with `q := p.item.linear_representation`. This is the most cumbersome method and I'm listing it only for completeness.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer the second option worked like a charm.